# Getting the average for multiple samples for variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a time-series data set with 5 minute resolution for 4 years in SAS. In this data set,a particular several variables (e.g., SRAD) is measured for each 5 minutes at 9 different stations (e.g., ST1,..., ST9). It means for each 5 minute interval (for example, Feb. 1, 2015 1:00:00 PM) there are 9 samples for this variable. Here is are some of my variables:

Interval  TAIR  SRAD  Date  Time  Month  Day    Year   Hour   Minute

Now, I am wondoering how I can create a new dataset including the data of Feb 1 to Feb 10, 2015 from 13-19 (time) with average of each variable from all stations. In other words, for each 5 min interval I need the average of all variables instead of 9 variables associated with the 9 stations (ST). Like this:

Interval  TAIR_ave   SRAD_ave   Date  Time  Month    Day     Year  Hour Minute

I need to do it in SAS. It'd be really appreciated if you can help.

Best Regards,
Paalang

Comment: I have to do the study only in SAS.

Comment: Per SO rules please post what you've tried.

Comment: And per SO rules, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the very least, *show* us with data and not *tell* us with text.